# How do I check if a list of lists contains a value?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get my program to repeat an operation on a list of lists until there are no zeroes in the entire thing. I decided to go with seventy lists of ninety zeroes each (this is being used for a maze generator).

```
x=int(input("How many columns?\n"))
y=int(input("How many rows?\n"))
maze=[[0]*x for n in range(y)]
```

So with the inputs 90 and 70, there should be a total of 6300 zeroes. However, when I use

```
while 0 in maze[:]:
    #stuff
```

...the loop ends instantly without doing anything. I've also tried

```
while 0 in maze:
    #stuff
```

It's like Python completely ignores every single one of the six thousand three hundred zeroes in the maze list. I know of a way to fix this, but it involves slowly scrolling through the range of y values for every iteration. Is there a simpler way that allows it to look at all of the sublists in one line?

Comment: Because 0 is not in maza, [0]*x is in, so it instantly break from the while function.... I suggest you use while True..

Comment: There is a simpler way that doesn’t involve “y values”, but it’s just as slow from a performance standpoint. (You have a list of lists, so you need to do the `in` check on every list, and you can do that with [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any).) Maybe you can keep a count of how many zeros remain instead, decrementing it in `#stuff` when appropriate?

Comment: `maze` is a list of lists. So there is no `0` there, only some objects of type `list`. However, inside *those* objects of type `list` you'll find some zeroes

Comment: `while 0 in maze:` doesn't work because maze does not contain `0` as a direct element.   `while 0 in maze[:]:`  creates an identical copy of maze and looks at the copy, so the outcome is the same.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `any()` function together with a generator expression:

```
while any(0 in sublist for sublist in maze):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you could use `numpy` array to do what you want. The `in` operator will not find `0` in your list of lists, bu would work as intended with numpy.

Minimal and verifiable example:

```
x = [[0,0,0,1], [1,2,3,1]]
>>> 0 in x
False

np_x = np.array(x)
>>> 0 in np_x
True
```

---

*Why `0 in x` won't work?*

Because `x` holds lots of objects of type `list`, and an object of type `list` will not be equal to `0` in any occasion. The `in` operator will not dig in to deepest level of your list to find out if there are zeroes there or not.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if 0 exists in a 2-D matrix is always going to cost O(n*m), which is rather inefficient especially since your loop is going to iterate many times.

For your purpose I would suggest that you simply use a counter and increment it whenever your operation inside the loop sets an item of 0 to a non-0 value, so that you can use something like this as a condition for the `while` loop:

```
while counter < x * y:
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `0` is `False` in Boolean and all the items in `maze` are going to be numbers, you can use this instead:

```
while not all(map(all, maze)):
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy does not convert it to array if your sub-lists have different sizes

So, you'd better unravel your list:

```
x = [[0,0,0,1], [1,2,3,1,4,3,22,-4]]
x_flat = [val for sublist in x for val in sublist]
0 in x_flat 
>> True
```